# Discord Bot Posting a Channel Link

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

This is what I have so far and it works.  I am trying to add a #channel-name-link at the end of the message.

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcome = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "on-the-leash");
    if (!welcome) return;
    welcome.send("Welcome " + member.toString() + "more message here!!" + message.guild.channels.cache.get('channelID').toString());
});
```

Now I am getting an error say that message is not defined.  I am new to node.js.  I am use to PowerShell and Bash.  I have programmed in Java and C++ but it has been a year or two since I really did anything with them.  I appreciate all the help.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Are you using discord.js v11 or v12?
Do you want to get the channel by using it's ID or would you rather find it using its name?

Edit:

Add `.cache` after `message.guild.channels`, that should fix your issue

Your solution would be:

```
welcome.send("Welcome " + member.toString() + "more message here" + message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "rules" ).toString());
```

OR

```
welcome.send("Welcome " + member.toString() + "more message here" + message.guild.channels.cache.get("channelID").toString());
```

Comment: I am using v12, and either way will work.  I know the ID on this channel, but might want to switch to name later if I ever need to.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work, I also noticed that my code was not showing up so now you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: No, you misunderstood what I said, I edited my answer again to give you the solution

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help @Syntle you got me where I needed to be

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcome = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "on-the-leash");
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('#ChannelID#').toString();
    if (!welcome) return;
    welcome.send("Welcome " + member.toString() + "More Message Here" + channel);
});
```